# Path with white spaces can't create a file using File.CreateText(filePath) c#

Tags: c#, file, path, streamwriter

I'm developing a console application that parse xml files and generate a txt file. I have created the file path to store the new file, but this is having white spaces, like this:

```
string filePath = "C:\\Program Files\\my path\\fileName.txt"
```

but I'm creating the path using:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(temp, "fileName.txt");
```

while temp is the previous path. And when I call:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath);
```

Is giving this exception:
Could not find a part of the path: filePath

Can someone help me with this issue?? how can I create the file with this path?

Comment: I doubt that it's white space causing the issue but you can use `filePath.Trim()` to remove all spaces in the string

Comment: how you get file path? this will not compile due to "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: What is temp?  Does it contain the filename too?  From your description, it sounds like you are duplicating the filename on the end of your path.  Can you print out the value of filePath just before you call the CreateText method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there looks like a problem with you file path

try`@"C:\Program Files\my path\fileName.txt"`

Note: You've updated your question with the changes mentioned in the comments.

Your issue is probably that 'my path' doesn't exist as this console application works OK for me when run as an administrator. When not run I get an UnathorizedAccessException

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var temp = @"C:\\Program Files\\my path\\";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(temp, "fileName.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("I got here");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't");
            //
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work... appears the same exception message. I think that my problem is that I'm creating the path using: filePath = Path.Combine(temp, "filename.txt"); then I write sw = File.CreateText(@filePath) and it doesn't work, any idea??

Comment: update your question with the code you are having the problem with.

Comment: what is the value of temp by they way?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Program Files\my path\fileName.txt"
```

Comment: This will result in 2 slashes after the drive letter

Comment: After a quick test, it appears that double slashes are ok after the drive letter.  I will remove this downvote if the answer is edited.

Comment: i think my original answer is correct, but was edited wrongly by Damith

Comment: I tested it and the double slashes didn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have single backslashes in the string. Make them double backslashes:

```
string filePath = "C:\\Program Files\\my path\\fileName.txt"
```

Comment: You need to use code block otherwise \\ will appear as \. I believe this doesn't deserve a down vote

Comment: Your answer was downvoted, probably because it wasn't formatted. Since you didn't use code blocks in your answer for string filePath line, the double backslash in the string was appearing as single backslash. I edited your answer so that it can reflect the double backslash